# azure yaml pipeline - name property from variables template file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have several build pipelines that have the same name property pattern:

```
name: $(date:yy).$(minorVersionPrefix)$(date:MMdd)$(rev:.r)
```

Instead of defining it in every file, I wanted to use global variables template yaml file and get build name defined from that file.

So what I would like to have is, in the pipeline yaml:

```
name: $(buildName)
variables:
- template: global.yaml
```

And inside global.yaml:

```
variables:
  minorVersionPrefix: '0'
  buildName: $(date:yy).$(minorVersionPrefix)$(date:MMdd)$(rev:.r)
```

The problem is that the syntax inside the global.yaml file does not work. I also tried template syntax but, for example, date is not defined there (variables.date is null).

Is there a way to generate build name globally and inject it as a variable value, or maybe it is possible to set name variable pattern from global variable as string in pre-processing phase so it is then interpreted as if it was in the pipeline file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm that the date variable is unavailable in Variable templates. However, we can use the [counter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) in variable templates. It evaluates a number that is incremented with each run of a pipeline.

For example:

Variable template Yaml: vars.yml

```
variables:
- name: major
  value: '1'
- name: minor
  value: '0'
- name: patch
  value: $[counter(format('{0}.{1}-{2}', variables['major'], variables['minor'], variables['Build.SourceBranchName']), 1)]
```

azure-Pipelines.yml

```
name: $(major).$(minor)-$(patch).$(Build.SourceBranchName)

trigger: none

variables:
- template: templates/vars.yml  # Template reference

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo xxx
```

In this way we still have to add the `name` in every yaml file. But we just need to adjust the value of the variables in template. It will apply the values to all pipelines using the variable template.

The build number is set like this:

[image]

Alternately, we can add a **steps template** with a script extending Pipelines functionality to update the build number by running [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number). See [I want to do something that is not supported by expressions. What options do I have for extending Pipelines functionality?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#i-want-to-do-something-that-is-not-supported-by-expressions-what-options-do-i-have-for-extending-pipelines-functionality).

For example:

Steps template: global.yml

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Preparing Build Number'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      #Set the minorVersion prefix per your requirement
      $minorVersionPrefix = "0" 
      Write-Host "minorVersionPrefix:" $minorVersionPrefix
      Write-Host "Original BuildNumber:" $(Build.BuildNumber)
      Write-Host "BuildId:" $(Build.BuildId)
      
      #splits the $(rev:.r)
      $MAJOR_RUN=$(echo $(Build.BuildNumber) | cut -d '.' -f1)
      echo "This is the major run number: $MAJOR_RUN"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=major]$MAJOR_RUN"

      $MINOR_RUN=$(echo $(Build.BuildNumber) | cut -d '.' -f2)  #By default, if you do not explicitly set the pipeline name with custom format, the value should be $(rev:.r) value. So we can set it as revision.
      echo "This is the minor run number: $MINOR_RUN"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minor]$MINOR_RUN"
      
      #Set date variables
      $currentDate = $(Get-Date)
      $year = $currentDate.Year
      $month = $currentDate.Month
      $day = $currentDate.Day
      Write-Host $currentDate
      
      #Set new buildNumber
      $buildNumber = "$year.$month.$day.$minorVersionPrefix.$MINOR_RUN"
      Write-Host "Setting the name of the build to $buildNumber."

      #Update the buildNumber with the new value
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildNumber"
```

azure-pipeline.yml:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- template: templates/global.yml
```

In this way we do not need to add `name` in pipelines, the script will update the `buildNumber` automatically using the patterns defined in the script. So, we just need to update the `patterns` in `global.yml` to make it take effect.

The build number will be updated like this:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

The included variable template can only be used to define variables but cannot pass variables. See [Variable reuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#variable-reuse) for details.

We can use variables inside of templates and can be used in expressions only, but doesn't include `$(date)` and `$(rev:.r)`, they are not available here. See [How can I use variables inside of templates?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#extend-from-a-template) for details.

The simplest way for you is to only set the `minorVersionPrefix: '0'` in variable template (`global.yml`). Then use the `name: $(date:yy).$(minorVersionPrefix)$(date:MMdd)$(rev:.r)` in your pipelines. Thus, you can control the minor version in `global.yml`.

Comment: Adding extra step is actually more complicated than initial problem.
Is there a way to somehow escape $() syntax in string literal in global.yaml file and apply that with ${{}} syntax in pipeline yaml files so it is resolved there, but its pattern is controled from a single place in global.yaml?

Comment: @mdzieg We cannot achieve that. We can use variables inside of templates but doesn't include `$(date)` and `$(rev:.r)`, they are not available here. See [How can I use variables inside of templates?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#extend-from-a-template) for details. The simplest way for you is to only set the `minorVersionPrefix: '0'` in variable template. Then use the `name: $(date:yy).$(minorVersionPrefix)$(date:MMdd)$(rev:.r)` in your pipelines. Thus, you can control the minor version in `global.yml`.

Comment: @mdzieg See the updated answer.

Comment: thank you for your help. I am not happy that there is no simple solution to this. I would love to be able to define 'patterns' that can be resolved once applied in place, instead of all variables being forced to be replaced where they are in code. I appreciate your willingness to help. Much appreciated. Take care.